# ListView manually size columns sizes (Excel)

Tags: excel, listview, vba

Just to say thanks for all of your help in the past regards various VBA questions in Excel. After some research and trial and error I have been recommended to use a listview rather than a listbox. So far so good - got the data I want and it does look better...but...I can only set the width for all of the column widths to a certain size. Ideally want to manually set the widths of the 10 columns - or possibly an autosize based on the header. But I would prefer choosing the widths. I will attach my code shortly.

==============================

Private Sub LoadListView()

```
'Declare the variables
Dim wksSource As Worksheet
Dim rngData As Range
Dim rngCell As Range
Dim LstItem As ListItem
Dim RowCount As Long
Dim ColCount As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long

'Set the source worksheet
Set wksSource = Worksheets("Sheet1")

'Set the source range
Set rngData = wksSource.Range("A1").CurrentRegion

'Add the column headers
For Each rngCell In rngData.Rows(1).Cells
    Me.ListView1.ColumnHeaders.Add Text:=rngCell.Value, Width:=53
Next rngCell

'Count the number of rows in the source range
RowCount = rngData.Rows.Count

'Count the number of columns in the source range
ColCount = rngData.Columns.Count

'Fill the ListView
For i = 2 To RowCount
    Set LstItem = Me.ListView1.ListItems.Add(Text:=rngData(i, 1).Value)
    For j = 2 To ColCount
        LstItem.ListSubItems.Add Text:=rngData(i, j).Value
    Next j
Next i
```

End Sub

Comment: So at the moment the only section I can set the value is here:

Comment: Me.ListView1.ColumnHeaders.Add Text:=rngCell.Value, Width:=53

Comment: So what's the issue with *manually* setting widths?

Comment: Hi, The problem is I don't know the right code to add add to my existing project to manually set the width of the columns. Ideally I want to keep my current code layout as it works fine - other than all of the columns are the same width.